# Wifi event automation software

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, powershell, script

I am having issues on my Asus F555UB-Laptop with the WiFi. As a workaround I have written a shell script that restarts the Wifi Adapter

```
#restart network adapter
Disable-NetAdapter -Name WLAN -Confirm:$false
Enable-NetAdapter -Name WLAN -Confirm:$false
```

However, it needs more automization. Because right now I have to execute the script myself when the signal is lost. It would be great if the script gets triggered when the WiFi gets disconnected, and after restarting the adapter it should automatically reconnect to an available WIfi I have a password stored for. So my Questions are:

- How can I trigger the script to run on a "lost wifi signal event"?
- How can I automatically connect to my Wifi?

Answer (score 2):

Create task, inside **Task Scheduler**, set **task trigger** to:

"**On an event**"

- Log: **Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational**
- Source: **NetworkProfile**
- EventID: **1001**

Task **Action** - task can call your PS script.

Comment: thank you very much :)

Comment: @cowboy_patrick Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you, that way other people searching will know this answer is correct, and give credit to the person that took their time to answer.